# Adaptec 2405 "Knight Rider" LEDs - fault?

Tags: hardware-raid, adaptec

I have an Adaptec 2405 installed on ESXi 5.0.  When the card is idle, it flashes the red LEDs back and forth, Knight Rider -style, just like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQytlgBwhPk).  Is this normal, or is this a fault? I have dug everywhere through the manuals and can't seem to figure it out.

If it is in a fault state, I can't get it to tell me anywhere that is the case.

Comment: [KITT has lost his memory]
KITT: "Don't touch Turbo Boost. Something tells me you shouldn't touch Turbo Boost."

Comment: The real fault is that more manufacturers don't do things like this.

Comment: I recall seeing our Adaptecs do this when the machine was still in POST, but they all went off after the card had initialised its own BIOS...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether our engineers were inspired by Cylons or KITT when they designed it I do not know, but I can tell you that this is normal behavior for our cards when there is no I/O.

Comment: @Chris S - While I understand your motive for making the edit you did, I think it is acceptable for some sort of indicator (in the answer body, not just the username) that this is a somewhat "official" reply from the OEM.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart [FAQ#Signatures](http://serverfault.com/faq#signatures) will be enforced with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @ChrisS Fair enough. I suppose the answerer should add said information in their profile then.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if my reply is correct (I don't have Adaptec 2405), but a little bit of Googling revealed you are not alone with your wondering.

Apparently that K.I.T.T. behaviour (or, "sweeping pattern" as described by some others) is normal and you can possibly disable that LED animation from the Adaptec BIOS settings. I, for one, would not disable that kind of awesomeness.

Comment: Nope I will definitely not be disabling it. Just wanted to make sure there was no fault!